# How do I turn off roaming profiles in Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, roaming-profile

Good Morning,

We are running Snow Leopard Server with Windows XP clients, we have about 10-12 user who logon with the same username and password, these users are telling us that they are seeing strange things as each of them log on and off, they are seeing things that some of the users save on the other computers?  It almost sounds like a roaming profile feature?  Any assistance greatly appreciated as we have several staff members frustrated at this point.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: We'll probably need more information on exactly what you're seeing to be able to help -- Your users haven't provided any info that points me in the direction of potential problems/solutions.  Can you reproduce the problem and describe the behavior in greater detail? Are there specific things that make it happen/not happen? etc.

Comment: certain things on their desktops are there sometimes and not there other times, IE favorites will be there for a user on a different pc, mostly recognizable from the desktop and my documents folder and IE favs. any thoughts or ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Mac OS X Server is able to manage Group Policy.
So in that case you would have to change that (Roaming profiles) settings on each machines.

Comment: The interesting thing is I did not enable roaming profiles in Windows XP and it would not be on by default, can anyone confirm?